# Using discord.py to filter out bad words, no other commands will work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a filter for bad words on my discord bot using discord.py. Here's my code so far:

```
with open('badwords.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    channel = bot.get_channel(my_log_channel)
    mybot = bot.get_user(my_bot_id)
    #.. some custom embed ..

    if message.author is mybot:
        return

    for badword in file:
        if badword in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

There are two main problems so far. The bigger one is that no other commands will execute.

I tried adding

```
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

to the end of the second if statement, but then every command is getting executed twice.

The second problem i'm having is that if I wanted to blacklist for example the word "ass" it also automatically deletes words like "pass" and so on. I would like to avoid this.

I would really appreciate some help on this, I'm kinda new to discord bots and I'm stuck here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `on_message` is a coroutine. You need to get an event loop and gather all of the coroutines you want to run. Can you add the code you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using a simple for loop to find the bad words works, people get creative and may use spacing to still say them, for example, **v e r y b a d w o r d**. You bot wouldn’t detect this and wouldn’t be able to delete this.

## Code

```py
import re
import string

separators = string.punctuation+string.digits+string.whitespace
excluded = string.ascii_letters

word = "badword"
formatted_word = f"[{separators}]*".join(list(word))
regex_true = re.compile(fr"{formatted_word}", re.IGNORECASE)
regex_false = re.compile(fr"([{excluded}]+{word})|({word}[{excluded}]+)", re.IGNORECASE)

profane = False
if regex_true.search(message.content) is not None\
    and regex_false.search(message.content) is None:
    profane = True
```

## Analysis

`separators` contains characters which can be inserted between the letters of a banned word while still being marked as profane.

`excluded` contains characters which can be inserted between the letters of a banned word and gets marked as not profane.

`separators` and `excluded` can be modified based on which characters should or shouldn't be allowed to divide profane words.

`word` is a sample bad word which will be tested to determine the validity of the regular expression.

`formatted_word` is an inclusive character set which matches zero or more of any of the characters in `separators`

`regex_true` returns a match object if a banned word is detected with any of the characters in `separators` are detected between the letters of the word. Note that the number of characters separating each letters is independent of the others, so 'w!o@#r$%^d' would return a match if 'word' is a banned word.

`regex_false` returns a match object when the banned word itself is detected with one of the characters in `excluded` either precedes or trails the word. This implies that the word is actually part of another word, e.g. 'ass' in 'pass'.

If `regex_true` returns a match object and `regex_false` does not, then the detected match should be considered to contain a banned word, given the above criteria.

## Examples

Given `word = "word"` and the above code is used, below are the results of various test messages. Remember that if there is a matching set for `regex_true` and not matching set for `regex_false`, then `profane = True`.

```py
>>> regex_true.search("word")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='word'>
>>> regex_false.search("word")
>>> #profane=True
```

```py
>>> regex_true.search("aworda")
<re.Match object; span=(1, 5), match='word'>
>>> regex_false.search("aworda")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='aworda'>
>>> #profane=False
```

```py
>>> regex_true.search("w1o~r d")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='w1o~r d'>
>>> regex_false.search("w1o~r d")
>>> #profane=True
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, i will implement that later today and report back. looks very promising!

Comment: Okay, I added this, and while it does filter out the bad words even with spaces, it still also filters out messages like "pass". Here's what I've done: (edit: sorry very new to this thing, code doesnt work well in comments lol)

Comment: I guess you could use the ‘^’ and/or ‘$’ to prevent that from happening.

Comment: sorry, i think i don't quite get what you mean by that

Comment: The characters require the string to start or end with the regular expression.

Comment: sorry for being dumb, but how would i add this to the code? i tried something like $badword and it just throws out errors

Comment: uh, i feel really bad for bugging you about this, but when i add the ^ or $ like you did, it doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: Okay let me reference my code and I’ll get back to you.

Comment: @moinierer3000 I experimented with the regular expressions and edited my answer to my best solution. I also added explanations for each part of the code and this all should work now.

Comment: wow! thank you **so** much for your help!

Comment: @monierer3000 Don't mention it :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing present in your file, then it won't even go inside the `for` loop. Also, if that specific bad word is not present in the message, it will call the remaining commands and go to the next word, that is why your commands are being called repeatedly.

So, try this:

```py
with open('badwords.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(my_log_channel)
    mybot = bot.get_user(my_bot_id)
    #.. some custom embed ..

    if message.author is mybot:
        return

    flag = False
    for badword in file:
        if badword in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            flag = True

    if not flag:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Yes that works, thank you so so much! Do you have by chance any idea of how to fix the second problem?

Comment: @moinierer3000 maybe add a space before and after the word? like check if `' ass '` or `' ass.'` is present in the message? Apart from this, I don't think there's any other way. It'll be better to give some kind of warning to the user rather than deleting the whole message.

Comment: I will try that later today and report back, thank you

Comment: @moinierer3000 the `regex` answer would actually be a better approach. It'll take a longer time tho.

Comment: The regex solution may be longer but it is more flexible and is more likely to pick up ‘hidden’ bad words.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @JacobLee, go with Regex. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use a text file, i made a list of filtered words, this is my code :

```
filtered_words = ["Example1","Example 2","ex 3"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in msg.content:
         await msg.delete()

    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for workarounds like "b a d w o r d" or "abadword", however.